# Apereo CAS site can't be reached

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I'm trying to deploy an Apereo CAS server for development/integration purposes. I've tried deploying both using the suggested docker image, and on a fresh 18.04 ubuntu installation.

In both cases I create a keystore in /etc/cas/keystore, with password changeit, and domain localhost in the docker case, and the public domain in the installation in the cloud.

The service seems to run with no issues, printing a READY message in ascii in the terminal console.

Port access is enabled for ports 8433, 8080.

However I don't seem to be able to access this from any browser. I've tried http://domain:8080/cas and https://domain:8433/cas or removing the cas appendix in the url.

I've tried with versions ranging from 5.2.2, 5.3.2, and the latest 6.0.0-RC4-SNAPSHOT.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a keystore file `thekeystore` under `/etc/cas`. Use the password `changeit` for both the keystore and the key/certificate entries.
- Ensure the keystore is loaded up with keys and certificates of the server.

Please change the keystore name to thekeystore. Make sure your keystore under the directory /etc/cas/and your cas.properties is under the directory /etc/cas/config in ubuntu not your cas poject folder {cas_HOME}/etc/cas . Try accessing  https://domain:8443/cas.

This is working for me. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to acknowledge this, but the cause was a typo in the port.

Expected port is 8443, and not 8433.

Having fixed that, it works now. Thanks!